# go back to a certain viewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

my Storyboard looks like:

[image]

User can go directly from the 1st screen to the 4th. The fourth screen contains tableView, with XIB cell design. I want user to be able to tap on a cell and get to the 3rd screen and send some data with that. I know this should be done in `didSelectRowAt`. But is it even possible?

Comment: picture is unavailable.

Comment: It should be available, I checked it in incognito mode. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwZx3.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

1. **Create a segue.** In your storyboard, ctrl-drag from the first button on top of your 4th screen to anywhere on your second screen. You should see a new segue created in your storyboard.
2. **Give the segue an id.** Click on the newly created segue, in the right panel, set the `indentifier` attribute under the Indentity Inspector tab.
3. **Perform the segue.** In your `didSelectRowAt`, add the following line:

```swift
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "THE_ID_YOU_ASSIGNED_IN_STEP_2")
```

4. **Send data to the destination segue.** In your screen 4 view controller, add the following function:

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "THE_ID_YOU_ASSIGNED_IN_STEP_2" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? YOUR_SCREEN_3_VC {
            // Send data to your VC, such as assigning values
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have a segue from 3rd screen to 4th. Is the picture available?

Comment: @Anatoly Rudenko That is 3 to 4. We want a 4 to 3 right?

Comment: You're right. What a shame, for some reason I thought you can't have two identical segues going opposite directions. thank you!